# Error while recording a RTSP stream with avconv

Tags: 12.04, avconv

I need to losslessly record a RTSP stream of an Axis 211a camera using avconv on Ubuntu 12.04. I am using this command :

```
avconv -rtsp_transport tcp -f rtsp -i rtsp://<IP>/mpeg4/media.amp -acodec copy -vcodec copy -y output.avi
```

It works most of the time, but sometimes I randomly (or so it seams) get an error that stops the recording after about 2 seconds :

```
Application provided invalid, non monotonically increasing dts to muxer in stream 1: 26158 >= 21471  
av_interleaved_write_frame(): Invalid argument
```

Obviously I need this to work 100% of the time, so if anyone has a solution to this it would be great. I've been looking around, apparently many people had a similar error but I can't seem to be able to find a solution.
Thanks,
G.